# Java constructor mockup

Tags: java, junit, constructor, mocking, jmockit

Could you please any one tell me How to mock up Java Constructor  ? I tried as below. But it doesn't work.

```
new MockUp<UserCompanyDivision>()
{ 
    @Mock
    public UserCompanyDivision(String com, String div)
    {
    }    
};
```

Comment: I guess [this](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#How_to_mock_construction_of_new_objects) should help.

Answer (score 2):

Since constructors don't have names like methods do, JMockit uses the special name "$init" for the corresponding `@Mock` *methods*. For example:

```
new MockUp<UserCompanyDivision>() {
    @Mock // matches a constructor having the same parameters
    void $init(String com, String div) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Note that this is described in the [API documentation](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Mock.html) for `@Mock`.